# Adding a value to each element of a column in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a value to each element of a column
For example:

1 
2 
3 
4 
5

to which I would like to add a value, let's say 5. The result I am after is:
6
7
8
9
10

It shouldn't be too hard but I don't know what function to use.

Thanks!

(on the website it shows the data like a row, but i am after a column, guessing the function will still be the same)

Comment: That's a rather simple question. I think you didn't even tried to solve it on your own. The simplest way one could think about it is just to take an vector, say $v$ and write in the command line $v + 5$. And indeed, that's the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 9):

Here you have every possibility:

```
x <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
```

add 5 to column 1:

```
x[, 1] + 5
```

add 5 to row 1:

```
x[1, ] + 5
```

add 1 to the first row, 2 to second, 3 to third:

```
x + 1:3
```

the same with columns:

```
t(t(x) + 1:3)
```

add 5 to all the cells:

```
x + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

R vectorizes operations (here: addition) automatically.

```
> c(1,2,3,4,5)+5
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

(Such questions are better at [StackOverflow in the R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).)

Comment: Thank you so much! (first time asking a question here, so wasn't sure how, and where to ask)

Comment: I'd suggest you read chapter 2 of "An Introduction to R" (which should be available in the Help menu item of your R GUI). This should bring you up to speed very quickly. Good luck!